# How to disable scaling the UI on Windows, for Java 9 applications?

Tags: scaling, java-9, compiler-flags, hidpi

There was no proper **HiDPI support** in Java 8.

In **Java 9**, JavaFx applications correctly scale to the monitor they are in. For example, if my monitor is set to scale at 150%, the Java application is scaled to 150%.

See: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/263

However, for testing purposes, I need to be able to **disable scaling** by using **java.exe flags**, in Windows 10. How can I achieve this?

Also, maybe I can disable (and re-enable) this programmatically within the application itself?

Comment: Do you not find any similar configuration on Windows as mentioned in [this answer?](https://superuser.com/a/1207925/528671)

Comment: @nullpointer Sure, but I need to do it through java.exe flags, not through a configuration on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JFrame scaling in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622712/jframe-scaling-in-java-9)

Answer (score 15):

I found this obscure option in a [substance bug report](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/substance/issues/48). This fixes the issue for Swing applications.

`-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0`

If you're using JavaFX you'll need

`-Dprism.allowhidpi=false`

Unfortunately I cannot find official documentation for either of these options

Comment: `System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1.0");` worked for me with JDK 11 and Swing, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

if needed, found another couple of helpful JVM parameters from [that website](https://news.kynosarges.org/2019/03/24/swing-high-dpi-properties/) :

```
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false
-Dsun.java2d.win.uiScaleX=1.0 -Dsun.java2d.win.uiScaleY=1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
System.setProperty( "sun.java2d.uiScale", "1.0" );
```

in your java code, that worked for me (JDK 17).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does not work for me on Windows 7 and JRE 9.0.4 for some reason