# Why is my JDK11 program affected by Windows 7 personalized display setting?

Tags: java

I use Windows 7 and have personalized the display to zoom in to medium setting (125%), making icons on the desktop bigger etc. Now when I changed from jdk8 to jdk11 I discovered the java applications are affected by this. What's going on and how do I avoid this?
So e.g. if I just create a simple JFrame and draw an image to it the frame is bigger than it should be, and the picture looks terrible.

Comment: See also: [Java disable dpi-aware not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30555401/5221149)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 9 introduced support for scaling in high-dpi displays: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/263

That would explain why you see this behavior change when going from jdk8 to jdk11.

Try the suggestions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48623068/701303

(for swing: `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0`; for javafx: `-Dprism.allowhidpi=false`)

Comment: Thank you, that did it.