# Different rendering in the simulation or using saveFrame() using Processing in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing, rendering

After many years with Processing IDE, I missed Intellij IDEA too much so I went back for it but Processing stays on :wink:

However, the shapes drawn are way less sharp than in the real PDE, for example, a simple circle is rendered differently using both time the latest version of Processing available 4.1.2, Java 17, the same PC and the same monitor :

In PDE :

```
public void setup() {
    size(500, 500);
}


public void draw() {
    background(40);
    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    circle(width/2, height/2, 400);
    saveFrame("./PDE.png");
    noLoop();
}
```

and the result is :

[image: saveFrame() or direct view using Processing IDE]

With Intellij however :

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Main extends PApplet {

    public void settings() {
        size(500, 500);
    }


    public void draw() {
        background(40);
        noStroke();
        fill(255);
        circle(width/2, height/2, 400);
        saveFrame("Intellij IDEA.png");
        noLoop();
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Main pt = new Main();
        PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{"testRendering"}, pt);
    }
}
```

the saveFrame() is exactly the same as with Processing IDE but the real view in the sketch is :[image: real view in the sketch with Intellij]

I guess that it is a problem of renderer but I can't change it using `fullScreen(P2D)` for example because it throws errors.
The only solution I found were using Maven but I am not so I'd rather find a solution for my problem.

Comment: Check if You have 1.25 UI scalling in Windows Screen Settings?

Comment: @Mruk I don’t have the problem with the processing’s IDE either…I guess the screen settings aren’t in fault

Comment: Processing's IDE is ignoring global Windows settings. Just make a test how it is in Idea and write the conclusion for us.

Comment: Ok I didn’t know that ! I will try it, I just assumed it wasn’t that because the 2 images are of the same size although one was taken through Intellij and the other with Processing’s IDE

Comment: I have indeed the 1.25 UI scaling in Windows and putting it at 100% makes the anti-aliasing work ! However would it be possible to put 100% only in Intellij and not affect the rest of my Windows ?

Comment: By the way - Where in the Project Structure did You import processing.core?

Comment: I imported the Processing/core/library in the libraries tab of the project structure, everything compiles and the import in my code is well recognized

Comment: OK, here is working solution for Your question:  -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0 
 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48623068/4885365)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem arises because the window is being scaled (according to windows scaling settings) but its content is not rendered in a higher resolution (hence the "jaggies").

It's a problem only with the default (Java AWT) renderer. To fix it:

- Call `System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1")` before `PApplet.runSketch()` -- this will prevent the window from being scaled.

An alternative solution is to use the JavaFX renderer (`size(500, 500, FX2D)`), which seems to behave correctly (the content renders at a higher resolution).

If however high DPI scaling is not desired with the `FX2D` renderer, you can call `System.setProperty("prism.allowhidpi", "false")`to disable it.